# Кулдаун с помощью модуля datetime

Tags: python, бот, aiogram, datetime

Передо мной стоит задача - сделать таймер кулдаун использования команды для бота.
Если подробнее, то после того, как человек использует команду мне нужно сделать кулдаун в 24 часа, также нужно, чтобы при попытке использовать команду снова отправлялось время которое осталось человеку ждать.
Какие то представления о библиотеке я имею, исходя из прочтений нескольких статей на просторах интернета, но из за различного рода ошибок выполнить задачу не могу.
Буду рад если поможете=)

P.S. можете предложить вариант с библиотекой отличной от datetime

P.S.2 если как-то поможет делу - для бота я использую библиотеку aiogram

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Дайте нам свои наработки и ошибки, которые вас останавливают. Добавьте их в вопрос. Для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом

Comment: Если вам подошёл ответ то примите его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как вам нужно знать когда была нажата кнопка, то вам придется это где-то хранить. Варианты - FSM или База Данных.
Покажу на примере FSM.

```
import time

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("__", reply_markup=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Создать персонажа', callback_data='push_button')
    ))


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="push_button")
async def push_button(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await call.answer()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if type(data.get('button_pushed')) is float:
            if time.time() - data['button_pushed'] < 86400:
                hour = int((86400 - (time.time() - data['button_pushed'])) / 3600)
                minute = int(((86400 - (time.time() - data['button_pushed'])) % 3600) / 60)
                second = int(((86400 - (time.time() - data['button_pushed'])) % 3600) % 60)
                await call.message.answer(f"Осталось ждать ещё {hour} часов {minute} минут {second} секунд")
                return

        data['button_pushed'] = time.time()
        await call.message.answer("Кнопка нажата")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Ну и на всякий напоминаю что при перезапуске бота, память (MemoryStorage) очищается. Если бот часто рестартится, то стоит юзать redis или mongoDB

СКРИН
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я еще забыл про дату, но так как вам нужно только 24 часа то хватит и времени

Answer (score 0):

Ну, раз вы не выкладываете свои наработки, ловите функцию которая работает на секундах обратного отсчета.

```py
import time
  
def countdown(t):
    while t:
        m, s = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = f'{m:02d}:{s:02d}'
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print('Ну вот и все, таймер закончился!')
  
  
t = input("Сколько секунд будем считать: ")
  
countdown(int(t))
```

Переработайте под свои нужды, для суток используйте 86400

Comment: aiogram асинхронный, потому стоит использовать вместо time.sleep    asyncio.sleep()

Comment: @oleksandrigo напишите свой ответ. По не так вобще лучше просто время хранить, чем забивать процессом место

Comment: в целом так и есть, ему ведь нужно еще и возвращать сколько осталось времени

Answer (score 0):

В примере я использовал `sqlite`, но вы можете использовать другую БД. И в идеале создать отдельный класс для работы c БД.
Если вам нужно время в другом формате можете использовать `datetime`.

```py
import time
import sqlite3

def get_time_now():
    return int(str(time.time()).split(".")[0])

def save_time(user_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Название вашей бд')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"UPDATE Название таблицы SET lastUse='{get_time_now()}' WHERE userId='{user_id}'")
    conn.commit()
    return True

def check_time():
    time_in_database = #Достаёте из бд время
    if get_time_now() - time_in_database >= 60 * 60 * 24 or time_in_database == 0:
        return True
    return False

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="push_button")
async def push_button(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if check_time():
        # Действия, которые будет происходить при нажатии
    else:
        await call.message.answer(f"Осталось ждать {time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime('Достаёте сюда время из бд' - get_time_now()))}")
    save_time(call.from_user.id)
```